# highlight-indentation-mode discontinue

Tags: indentation, python

I am using spacemacs. When enabling `highlight-indentation-mode` in `python-mode`, I found that the vertical lines are not continue, they will be interrupted if there is an empty line. How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: This is not something you can fix. it's how emacs does highlighting indentation. All the lines which are empty are not highlighted (which makes sense if you think about it. If there's nothing in the line, there was no indentation made)

Comment: Depending upon how much time anyone wishes to invest, it is possible to create overlays in no-man/woman's land -- the overlay property is called `after-string`.  For an example of how this might work, see `vline.el`.  I'm not suggesting that `vline.el` is the answer to this question -- I'm only stating that it is a classic example of how to create overlays where there is no text (i.e., seemingly floating in no-man/woman's land).

Comment: In case someone stumbles upon this question: it was most probably related to [highlight-indentation-mode](https://github.com/antonj/Highlight-Indentation-for-Emacs/) which was never a _built-in_ Emacs package. As of today, [one more optional package](https://github.com/DarthFennec/highlight-indent-guides/blob/master/highlight-indent-guides.el) seems to be a good alternative.